# mysql insert to database no value

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to insert values on form submit but no result nothing is entering in the databse not even empty values,

```
if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname)
    VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin')");
}
```

i checked if theres connection to database and it's connected.
ANYONE ?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Also please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.

Comment: no errors, what do i use ?

Comment: does `mysql_error()` return anything? Link: [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). Although, note the red box, these functions are deprecated.

Comment: try `mysql_query(your query) or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname) VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin')") or die(mysql_error()); show me this

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: maybe `isset($_POST['signup'])` is false ?

Comment: try to debug $_POST['signup'];

Answer (score 2):

Execute the query directly in query browser or any of mysql editors and check whether it is inserted. If it is inserted successfully, just check like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {  
    echo "Inside";
    exit;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname)
    VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin')");
}
```

If it doesn't display **Inside**, then the problem is in `if(isset($_POST['signup']))`. Check it.

Comment: how query will execute when you exist before query ?

Comment: In this case, the query won't execute. But he has to know whether the control comes inside the if condition. If it wont come, the condition fails. So he can come an conclusion that the problem is in $_POST['signup'].